# How Do You Set a SQL Backup to URL Blob Retention Period Greater than 30 Days?

Tags: sql-server, backup, azure-sql-database

How can a retention period be configured to delete SQL backup blobs older than some custom duration, such as 180 days?

The existing command only permits a max of 30 days:

```
use msdb;
GO
EXEC smart_admin.sp_set_db_backup 
                @database_name='TestDB' 
                ,@enable_backup=1
                ,@retention_days = 30
                ,@credential_name ='MyCredential'
                ,@encryption_algorithm ='AES_256'
                ,@encryptor_type= 'Certificate'
                ,@encryptor_name='MyBackupCert'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is [fully documented](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn449497(v=sql.120).aspx) :

```
-- Enable and Configure SQL Server Managed Backup to Windows Azure for a Database

Use msdb;
GO
EXEC smart_admin.sp_set_db_backup 
                @database_name='TestDB' 
                ,@enable_backup=1
                ,@retention_days =30  --->>>>>>>>>> this is your RETENTION e.g. 30 Days
                ,@credential_name ='MyCredential'
                ,@encryption_algorithm ='AES_256'
                ,@encryptor_type= 'Certificate'
                ,@encryptor_name='MyBackupCert'
GO
```

EDIT:

> The retention period is specified in days and **can range from 1 to 30**. The retention period determines the recoverability time frame for the database.

Comment: I am aware of this command, thanks, but 30 is the max permitted by it.  What if I want 180 days?

Comment: @Guessed 1 through 30 is the max. You cannot have 180 days as retention.

Comment: What if corporate policy is 730 days retention?  How would I restore an 8 month old blob backup if requested?

Comment: I assume you have to find a method to transfer the backups to your defined storage or on prem. I am not sure as to how you can increase the retention period - you can open a case with MS and the Azure team is quiet welcoming to address your issue.